# WordPress 3: How to have more blog pages on the same site?

Tags: wordpress, blogs

I want to have 2-3 blogs with different URLs in my website and also have different content for each one. Say one is about Video, another about Text and another about Images (just an example).

How can I do that? I have to change the theme or is it a WP settings thing only?

**EDIT:**
It must be on the same domain like:
mysite.com/text/
mysite.com/image/
mysite.com/video/

Where /text/, /image/ and /video/ are all Pages created in WP and with a custom template file. However, instead of having static content written in the Rich Text Editor, I want it to contain blog posts.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I'd use the [Custom Taxonomy API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies) to create a new taxonomy and three terms (text, image, video) OR you could create a custom taxonomy for each so you could still have categories in each type.

EDIT (from comment left below): you should read up on [Custom Post Types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) as well. In thinking about it, the custom post type would work better.

Comment: Hmm, I'll give that a read as I have no idea what taxonomy is (yet). Thank you.

Comment: you should read up on [Custom Post Types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) as well.  In thinking about it, the custom post type would work better.

Comment: The Custom Post Type is perfect. Just what I needed. Thanks a lot, Darren.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for a "blog network": http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network.

Otherwise, you can install a different WordPress instance for each blog.

In the first case, you would install one WordPress instance on your server, then configure it to achieve your specific needs (you'll find answers on the link provided).

Or, you could just install a WP instance for each blog, on each folder.

Comment: WordPress MU no longer exists - multi-site functionality is now built into WordPress.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. How can I use this for my purposes?

Answer (score 1):

I've created something like that with the wordpress categories! the new menu options (Appearance - Menus) can make a category as menu link.

The wordpress plugin 'WP No Category Base' removes '/category' from your category permalinks and make urls like

- mysite.com/text/
- mysite.com/image/
- mysite.com/video/

Comment: That's one way, but I'd rather not as I still want to keep categories, sometimes even have cattegories cross-blog so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

make subdomain such as yourname.com or blog.yourname.com or blog1.yourname.com or yourname.com/blog1 or yourname.com/blog2 and make as much as domains using your cpanel or wotever the tool offered by the hosting company.

later install WP on each of these subdomain. You can use fantastica for this which will b easier else you need to manualy upload files and do it. :)

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. I have edited the question for a more clearer request.

Answer (score 0):

ign is right. You can either use WordpressMU (best choice in my opinion) or you install a WordPress instance for each blog.
 [Here you have some info](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_Multiple_Blogs)